# Failed deploying jHipster app on Heroku. Error -> "/bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found"

Tags: heroku, jhipster

The build succeeded successfully but it failed  when releasing the app with the error: /bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found

Does anyone encounter such a problem before?

Comment: There's a bug report, that this is not a jhipster-bug here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9426.

Comment: You may have a look at [Dockerfile : /bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74597445/dockerfile-bin-sh-1-mvnw-not-found-error/75234575#75234575) for workaround.