# Dockerfile : /bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found error

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, dockerfile

I am building a Docker container using the following `Dockerfile` and actually the app is running on the created container.

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy as builder
RUN addgroup demogroup; adduser --ingroup demogroup --disabled-password demo
USER demo
WORKDIR /app

# copy pom.xml, mvnw and source code
COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw ./
COPY pom.xml ./
COPY src/ src

#RUN dos2unix ./mvnw
RUN ./mvnw clean install  <-- this line gives error


# Second stage: minimal runtime environment
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy
WORKDIR /app

# copy jar from the first stage
COPY --from=builder /app/target/*.jar /app/app.jar

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

When executing `RUN ./mvnw clean install` line, I get " /bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found" error. I tried many things, but cannot fix it. Is there any problem in my Dockerfile?

Comment: The Dockerfile looks ok to me. What exactly are the errors you are getting when you say it 'cannot create jar files, etc'???

Comment: The system can't find `./mvnw` because it doesn't exists there. You are using a JDK image as a base, you should use a Maven one to build.

Comment: Thanks, but the same Dockerfile was working when I run it on my local and then after pushing to GitHub and then cloning it, it does not work. So, it may be related to line endings rather than using Maven, but in any case it would be better to build also Maven. So, could you please post an example about the proper usage with this Dockerfile? I know how to add it, but not sure which part of the current Dockerfile should be removed or changed.

Comment: Does `mvnw` have the correct permission in git? Is the execute bit set? Sounds like your local checkout has it and it git it doesn't. Can you run it if you clone your repo into a fresh target directory?

Comment: Hi Joachim, actually I tried with a fresh directory by cloning the app and this problem started after that point. I opened a new question regarding to this issue and if it is better, I think I should also use Maven image. Could you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74600387/building-dockerfile-with-maven-jdk-and-jre

Comment: Your new question is essentially identical to this one.  In addition to the things @JoachimSauer suggests, the other common cause of a problem like this on a Windows host is in fact the line endings.  If you `RUN dos2unix` or a `sed` command to change the line endings in the `mvnw` script in the Dockerfile, does that improve things?

Comment: (It looks like you edited the question to change from running `mvn` out of the `maven` image to running an in-repository `./mvnw` against a JDK image, and I think that's part of why you're getting confusing advice around that baes image.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I already tried all the things and none of them is working.

Comment: On the other hand, you can help me about the last update for that question.

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN mvn
```

runs mvn inside the docker image.

The docker image is basically a pared down Linux image. Or a Windows image, or whichever OS was used as the base image.

Presuming your base image is Linux, after docker build completed, at your project folder, you can do
docker run -it

and you will be in your dockerized Linux image, where you can run basic Linux commands (provided your image has those basic commands installed).

You can then navigate and inspect if your docker image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your good explanations. I decided to use `RUN ./mvnw clean install` command, but it gives error: "/bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found" and cannot fix it. I do not want to get Maven image and want to directly use mvnw in the project. I thisnk the problem may be related line endings on Wndows10, but cannot fix still. Can you have a look at my Dockerfile added to the Update?

Comment: 1. It's better to build a Linux based docker image to avoid licensing fees. 2. Most questions and answers relate closer to Linux images

Comment: 3. If you are experimenting with docker images, it would mean you are very proficient in shell cmd.  With proficiency in shell cmd , you would already know why ./mvnw would not work. I don't wish to offend you, but you really need to gain proficiency in CLI whether windows or Linux to be a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, include `Maven build` in your `Dockerfile` instead of running maven command from project folder via `mvnv`:

```
COPY src/main/resources/data/ ./src/data
```